# Passing Variables from HTML to Java(JSP)

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working on a web applet. I am using JDBC to connect to a psql database, in which I am running a query to return. Right now I have a drop down list that will help determine how the query will be structured. My drop down list options are set up like this:

```
<option value="Location A">Location A</option>
```

Is there anyway that I can pass this value into my java function which header looks like:

```
<%
out.print("HOW DO I PRINT THE ABOVE VARIABLE);
%>
```

Regards,
Sudo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your html is like

```
<select name='foobar'>
<option value='0'>0</option>
<option value='0'>1</option>
</select>
```

When submitted to your JSP, normally you can do

```
request.getParameter("foobar");
```

Comment: Wow awesome response and very timely! So would I be able to set this to a variable? Like `int parameter = request.getParameter("foobar");`

Comment: Yes. But the type returned from getParameter is a String. You'd need to call Integer.parseInt to convert it into an int